# Find maxima from the middle

Tags: arrays, r, perl, matrix

I have to find the closest maxima of a dataset from the middle of the dataset. The dataset may look something like this:

```
46813471    2
46813481    2
46813491    2
46813501    2
46813511    2
46813521    2
46813531    3
46813541    2
46813551    2
46813561    2
46813571    2
46813581    2
46813591    2
46813601    2
46813611    2
46813621    2
46813631    3
46813641    9
46813651    14
46813661    20
46813671    32
46813681    45
46813691    58
46813701    69
46813711    87
46813721    96
46813731    104
46813741    102
46813751    96
46813761    86
46813771    75
46813781    65
46813791    51
46813801    35
46813811    24
46813821    14
46813831    9
46813841    8
46813851    5
46813861    4
46813871    5
46813881    5
46813891    4
46813901    3
46813911    3
46813921    3
46813931    3
46813941    3
46813951    2
46813961    1
46813991    2
46814001    2
46814011    2
46814021    2
46814031    2
46814041    2
46814051    2
46814061    2
46814071    1
46814091    2
46814101    2
46814111    2
46814121    2
46814131    2
46814141    2
46814151    2
46814161    2
46814171    2
```

Please keep in mind that the actual dataset is quite large and that the pattern repeats. How would I go about getting the closest maxima from the middle, a specific point, for example say the row 46813621 in column 1? I'm calling R from perl and I'd probably be passing in an array, which will have the data and I'd specify an index. Then, R would get the closet maximum from that point and return to perl the index and the actual maxima value.

All help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what's "closest maxima from the middle" and I don't see your post explaining it either. Care to elaborate?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, read over your file while splitting your columns into an array use an index of 0 to $#array max. Take your max and add it to your total for each line, use a counter to increment and use List::Util qw(max) to calculate average maxima.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from my research the best way to find local maxima for data like this (which I assume is a time series) is the `turnpoints` function from the `pastecs` library..

```
library(pastecs)
data <- read.table("Untitled.txt")
tp <- turnpoints(data[,2])

dist_from_middle <- function(x, middle) {
    sqrt((x-middle)^2)
}
peaks = extract(tp, pit=0)
distances = sapply(data[,1], dist_from_middle, middle=46813621)
data <- data.frame(data, peak = peaks, distance = distances)

peaks <- data[which(data$peak==1),]
#         V1  V2 peak distance
#7  46813531   3    1       90
#27 46813731 104    1      110
#42 46813881   5    1      260
#58 46814061   2    1      440
closest_peak <- peaks[which(peaks$distance==min(peaks$distance)),]
#        V1 V2 peak distance
#7 46813531  3    1       90
```

Your sample data happens to illustrate one of the pitfalls of this approach, namely that there is a tiny local maxima that happens to be slightly closer to your point of reference. You can try to avoid this by specifying a p-value cutoff for the peaks (p-values are generated by `turnpoints`):

```
sig_extrema <- data[tp$tppos[which(tp$proba < 0.05)],]
sig_maxima <- sig_extrema[which(sig_extrema$peak==1),]
closest_maxima <- sig_maxima[which(
    sig_maxima$distance==min(sig_maxima$distance)),]
#         V1  V2 peak distance
#27 46813731 104    1      110
```

Which is probably the datapoint you were hoping for..

Answer (score 0):

closest local maximum in the positive direction:

```
  wpos <- which( diff( X[ ( length(X)/2 ):length(X) ] ) < 0)[1]
```

in the negative direction:

```
  wneg <- which( diff( X[ ( length(X)/2 ):1 ] )    ) < 0)[1]  

 which.min(wpos, wneg)
```

Peak finding does have its pitfalls, though.